# How to change this code so that it returns a string instead of an array?

Tags: javascript

I found myself using a lot of `.replace.replace`. So I decided to create a function that receives regexes as argument and uses them to replace substrings inside a string. I wanted to return a value, so I decide to use `map` instead of `forEach`:

```js
const contents = `"Some text"

<!-- Some comment-->


More text`

const HTMLCommentsRegex = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g
const multipleLinesRegex = /\n\n{2,}/g

const regexes = [{
  pattern: HTMLCommentsRegex,
  replacement: ''
}, {
  pattern: multipleLinesRegex,
  replacement: ''
}]

console.log(multiReplace(contents, regexes))

function multiReplace(contents, regexes) {
  const result = regexes.map((regex) => {
    return contents.replace(regex.pattern, regex.replacement)
  })
  return result
}
```

But I immediately realized my error. I'm returning an array instead of a string (like the original content of `contents`).

How to modify this code so that the function returns a string instead?

Desired output (basically removing HTML comments and multiple empty lines):

```
const contents = `"Some text"

More text`
```

Comment: What is the content of result array?

Comment: If you always replace it with `""`, you could create an alternation with `|` like this: `/<!--[\s\S]*?-->|\n\n{2,}/`

Comment: `.map()` creates a new array from the current one by passing each of the current elements through a mapping function. So, it's a the result is 1:1 with the input. You need a `forEach` or `reduce` or a regular loop to get a single result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `.reduce` instead - on each iteration, carry out the replacement on the accumulator, and return the new replaced string:

```js
const contents = `"Some text"

<!-- Some comment-->


More text`

const HTMLCommentsRegex = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g
const multipleLinesRegex = /\n\n{2,}/g

const regexes = [{
  pattern: HTMLCommentsRegex,
  replacement: ''
}, {
  pattern: multipleLinesRegex,
  replacement: ''
}]

const multiReplace = (contents, regexes) => regexes.reduce(
  (str, { pattern, replacement }) => str.replace(pattern, replacement),
  contents
);

console.log(multiReplace(contents, regexes))
```